# Select data based on week and year

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-select-db

I have this sql :

```
SELECT YEAR(`end`) as week, WEEK(`end`) as year
FROM table
WHERE week=24 AND year=2016
```

But I get the error `Unknown column week in where clause`. What I'm doing wrong ? Help me please. Thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can not use alias in `where` clause, try this;)

```
SELECT WEEK(`end`) as week, YEAR(`end`) as year
FROM table
WHERE WEEK(`end`)=24 AND YEAR(`end`)=2016
```